# How to pass button integer in other controller? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer

I have 2 buttons. I want to pass `index = 1` in next `viewController` if first button was pressed and `index = 2` if second button was pressed. How can I do it?

Code doesn’t work

**FirstController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;
```

**FirstController.m**

```
-(IBAction)Method1:(id)sender
{
self.index = 1;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
}

-(IBAction)Method2:(id)sender

{
self.index = 2;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{    nextViewController *dvc=[segue destinationViewController]; 
  dvc.index= _index;
}
```

**next.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;
```

**next.m**

```
if (self.index == 2){
    _data1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],nil];
      }
```

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController setIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faff1f18c30'`

Comment: Your question is too broad. Is index declared in both current VC and next VC ? How did you declare them ? How did u declare index ?

Comment: also pls show your button IBaction. and what you have tried to send this index value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tell you now.I use XIB here.Now I have 2 buttons in RootViewController.

First I set the button tag in view of button in the XIB

Then programmatically I set the button tag inside the button action method.

```
- (IBAction)actionGoFirstViewController:(id)sender
{
  // This is for getting button tag from the button view of XIB
  UIButton *btnFirst = sender; 
  //OR else I can set the button tag here.
  btnFirst.tag = 1;
  FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
  firstVC.intFirstBtntag = btnFirst.tag;
    //OR directly We can set the tag.
  firstVC.intFirstBtntag = 1;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstVC animated:YES];
 }

- (IBAction)actionGoSecondViewController:(id)sender
{
  // This is for getting button tag from the button view of XIB
  UIButton *btnSecond = sender;
  //OR else I can set the button tag here.
  btnSecond.tag = 2;
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
  secondVC.intSecondButtonTag = btnSecond.tag;
  //OR directly We can set the tag.
  secondVC.intSecondButtonTag = 2;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblFirstButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger intFirstBtntag;
@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
@end  
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize lblFirstButtonIndex;
@synthesize intFirstBtntag;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  lblFirstButtonIndex.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The First Button Tag is - %ld",(long)intFirstBtntag];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionBackRootView:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSecondButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger intSecondButtonTag;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@end
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize lblSecondButtonIndex;
@synthesize intSecondButtonTag;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 lblSecondButtonIndex.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Second button Tag is - %ld",(long)intSecondButtonTag];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)actionBackToRoot:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that in your second UIViewController you have something like:

```
class SecondViewController:UIViewController{
    var index:Int!
}
```

Then in your first UIViewController your going to have something like:

```
class FirstViewController : UIViewController{

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_first_second"{
            if let index = sender as? Int{
                 let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
             secondViewController.index = index
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func firstButtonTapped(sender:UIButton){
        let index = 1
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_first_second", sender: index)
    }

    @IBAction func firstButtonTapped(sender:UIButton){
        let index = 2
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_first_second", sender: index)
    }
}
```

**Note: You need to link the IBAction to your buttons. Also need to establish a segue between you two controller or you can create the presentation the new controller by code (presentViewController modally  o push on a UINavigationController)**

**Also if you want, you can create only one IBAction (set to you're buttons) and base on the Tag property, set to the sender property of performSegue.**

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
var index = 0

@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    index = 1
}

@IBAction func button2(sender: UIButton) {
    index = 2
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NextViewController {
            nextVC.index = index
        }
    }
}

//If not storyBoard

func pushToNext() {
    let nextVC = NextViewController()
    nextVC.index = index
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
}
```

Objective-C

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NextViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *button2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.index = 0;

    self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:YourFrame1];
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:YourFrame2];
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)clickButton1 {
    self.index = 1;
}

- (void)clickButton2 {
    self.index = 2;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your identifier"]) {
        NextViewController *nextVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextVC.index = self.index;
    }
}

- (void)pushToNextVC {
    //Storyboard
    NextViewController *nextVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your storyboard identifier"];

    //Not storyboard
    NextViewController *nextVC = [[NextViewController alloc]init];

    nextVC.index = self.index;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Update my question

Answer (score 0):

first declare index in this ViewController and when you click first button method write index=1; same for second button and the in prepare for segue method do this

DestinationViewController *dvc=[segue destinationViewController];
dvc.index=index;

Comment: Update my question

Comment: updated your question are you performing only one segue through your firstViewController

Comment: hi i have updated your segue please go through it the answer is there